# Parsing a string, Grammar file

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, text-parsing

How would I separate the below string into its parts. What I need to separate is each < Word > including the angle brackets from the rest of the string. So in the below case I would end up with several strings 1. "I have to break up with you because " 2. "< reason >" (without the spaces) 3. " . But Let's still " 4. "< disclaimer >" 5. " ."

```
I have to break up with you because <reason> . But let's still <disclaimer> .
```

below is what I currently have (its ugly...)

```
boolean complete = false;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
        while (complete == false) {
        if (s.charAt(end) == '<'){
            stack.add(new Terminal(s.substring(begin, end)));
            begin = end;
        } else if (s.charAt(end) == '>') {
            stack.add(new NonTerminal(s.substring(begin, end)));
            begin = end;
            end++;
        } else if (end == s.length()){
            if (isTerminal(getSubstring(s, begin, end))){
                stack.add(new Terminal(s.substring(begin, end)));
            } else {
                stack.add(new NonTerminal(s.substring(begin, end)));
            }
            complete = true;
        }
        end++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using a [`StringTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
for (String token : text.split("(?=<)|(?<=>)")) {
    boolean isNT = token.startsWith("<");
    System.out.format("%s |%s|%n", isNT ? "NT" : " T", token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually using a [BreakIterator](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5577) would be a better way of doing this.

> The BreakIterator class also provides
>   static getCharacterInstance(),
>   **getWordInstance**, and getLineInstance()
>   methods. These methods return
>   BreakIterator instances that allow you
>   to parse at the character, word, and
>   line level, respectively.